# Google Product Search API - See merchants and prices

Tags: google-search-api, google-product-search

So I am trying to get the list of sellers and prices as seen here (as an example)

http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=call+of+duty+modern+warfare+3&hl=en&cid=3184753655595438210&os=sellers

I am trying to do a product comparison of single products, and need to use the data here to pull into a database and store.

Using Google's shopping search API (as below) I expected it to return this info, however it only seems to return products without that list of merchants.

http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html

and

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=########################################&country=gb&q=call+of+duty+modern+warfare+3&alt=atom
```

**My Question:** How do I pull a list of merchants and their prices from the google product search API. If its not possible, are there any other feeds or such I can use to do the same thing?

**Edit:** Been playing around with the crowdBy rule but still cant seem to get it to return multiple vendors for each product.

Comment: take it this is not possible then?  did you work it out i know its old but wondering / trying the same myself

Comment: I didnt resolve it exactly as I wanted. I ended up having to find the product, get the GTIN, then do a query on that gtin instead of the product name, which would return each of the merchants that stock that exact product. The only problem is that you still get the same product spread across multiple GTIN's, so you have to choose one with the most merchants to compare from which isnt ideal

Comment: What about using https://serpapi.com/shopping-results ?